# Writing to stream using ternary operator ? in C++

Tags: c++, stream, ternary-operator

I have several points of type `double`. I want to write them in the stream only when they are not `0`. Also I have to say which one it is, like this:

`x1=" value "`

`y1=" value "` and so on..

Is there any way to do it like this:

```
    << ( (x1 != 0) ?  ( "x1=\"" << x1 << '"' )  : ' ') )
    << ( (y1 != 0) ?  ( "y1=\"" << y1 << '"' )  : ' ') )
```

or I have to make several `if` `else` statements?

Comment: Have you tried running this and gotten undesirable behavior? It looks fine to me....when in doubt push play and see if it works....

Comment: Actually, I see a problem: it's the "" << x1 << "" as part of the ternary expression

Comment: `( "x1=\"" << x1 << '"' ) ` is not right. You can't do that.

Comment: Yes, it covers `"x1=\""` part in red and says "Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

Comment: @RSahu so I guess I have to do it with `if` `else` statements, right?

Comment: Yes. See [Remy Lebeau's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38022731/434551).

Comment: @user5692938 not necessarily. Consider my answer

Comment: Thank to all, now it's more clear to me :)

Comment: If it is helpful, considering marking an answer :)

Comment: Are doubles (x1, y1) ever exactly 0.0?  Or is it just rarely so?

Comment: @Assimilater unfortunately I don't have 15 points :D

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN each figure has like 5-6 points, and if one of them is not given, it's default is `0`, so yes - they are very often

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: a `double` *can* be exactly `0.0`, yes. But whether or not a runtime calculation actually produces `0.0` *exactly* or produces a close approximation like `0.0000000001` instead is another matter. When using floating-point values, you should never trust absolute comparisons (eg: is `x1` exactly equal to `0`?), always use epsilon comparisons instead (eg: is `x1` *within 0.00001* of `0`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `<<` operator as part of an expression that isn't attached to a streamable object on the left side, like `std::ostream`.

What I might suggest if you have a group of `double` variables is to consider looping over them. That's an improvement from "several `if-else` statements". Put them in an array or other object you can iterate over: i.e:

```
// Example using 10 elements
#define N 10
double nums[N];
// ... code
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    if (nums[i] != 0) {
        cout << "nums[" << i << "]=\"" << nums[i] << "\"";
    }
}
```

To maybe help clarify why this is, consider breaking up each `<<` as a function call (essentially what's going on under the hood):

```
(((std::cout << "string1") << 10) << std::endl);
```

`std::cout << "string1"` resolves to something like

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const char* str) {
    // Ouptut the string
    return stream;
}
```

This allows the "chaining" effect of being able to use successive `<<` operators because each operator call resolves to the same `ostream`.

Answer (score 7):

The code will not work as shown.  The two operands of the `?:` operator must evaluate to the same data type.  In your example:

- the left operand is not even valid code.  Expressions like `( "x1=\"" << x1 << '"' )` are invalid because you cannot stream a `double` or a `char` into a string literal (equivalent to a `const char[]`).  But if it were valid code, it would evaluate to a `std::ostream&`, which is the standard output type of an `<<` operator.
- the right operand is a `char`.

Since they don't match types, you cannot use `?:`.  You will have to break up the code using `if` statements instead:

```
if (x1 != 0)
    mystream << "x1=\"" << x1 << '"';
else
    mystream << ' ';

if (y1 != 0)
    mystream << "y1=\"" << y1 << '"';
else
    mystream << ' ';
```

Comment: Not only that `( "x1=\"" << x1 << '"' )` is an expression by itself but it is not right. You can't use `<<` between a string literal and a `double`.

Comment: @RSahu this answer doesn't use parenthasis so it resolves to something more like my answer.

Comment: @Assimilater, true. I was talking about the code in OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You may invoke a stream manipulator taking a lambda:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Manipulator {
    using function_type = std::function<void (std::ostream&)>;
    function_type function;
    Manipulator(function_type function) : function(function) {}
};

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const Manipulator& manipulator) {
    manipulator.function(stream);
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    std::cout
        << Manipulator([a](std::ostream& stream) { if(a) stream << "a=\"" << a << '"'; })
        << Manipulator([b](std::ostream& stream) { if(b) stream << "b=\"" << b << '"'; })
        << '\n';
}
```

Note: C++14 generalized lambda capture allows replacing `std::ostream&` by `auto&`.

Comment: Probably a little overkill, but ya...you *could* do something like that...maybe it would be useful in some contexts, though I can't think of any off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

here shorten version of @Dieter Lücking's approach

you can use lambda just like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    [](std::ostream& stream, int x)->std::ostream& { if(x) stream << "b=\"" << x << '"'; return stream;}(std::cout, a);
    [](std::ostream& stream, int x)->std::ostream& { if(x) stream << "b=\"" << x << '"'; return stream;}(std::cout, b) << std::endl;
}
```